# First Build is fine, but hot-module-replacement causes Typerror: CB is not a function, using parcel.js

Tags: reactjs, postcss, react-css-modules, hot-module-replacement, parceljs

This is my first `react` project using `parcel` as the bundler. I have loved the speed and ease of the development server up to the point I started integrating `react-css-modules`. Honestly, I'm not sure what is causing my error, so any insight here would be appreciated.

In my terminal, `hot-module-replacement` is firing without error. I can rebuild my app in milliseconds when saving any change. In fact, the browser will update any changes to css, but functionality is killed due to a `javascript` error:

```
react-dom.development.js:15834 Uncaught TypeError: cb is not a function
    at react-dom.development.js:15834
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at hmrAccept (react-dom.development.js:15833)
    at react-dom.development.js:15713
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at WebSocket.ws.onmessage (react-dom.development.js:15710)

(anonymous) @ react-dom.development.js:15834
hmrAccept @ react-dom.development.js:15833
(anonymous) @ react-dom.development.js:15713
ws.onmessage @ react-dom.development.js:15710
```

I've traced this back to my call of `ReactDom.render()`

I'm not sure if this is a configuration error on my part of if I need to submit a bug on `github`. Any help is appreciated.

**index.js**

```
import "babel-polyfill";
import React from 'react';
import * as ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
// cross-browser support for CSS variables
import cssVars from 'css-vars-ponyfill';
cssVars();

import './index.css';
import App from './Components/App'

const rootEntry = document.getElementById('form-root')
ReactDOM.render( <App/>, rootEntry);
```

**.babelrc**

```
{
    "plugins": [
        ["react-css-modules", {
            "generateScopedName": "[path]__[name]__[local]__[hash:base64:5]",
            "webpackHotModuleReloading": true,
            "handleMissingStyleName": "warn"
        }]
    ],
    "presets": [
        ["env", { "useBuiltIns": true }], "react"
    ]
}
```

**.postcssrc**

```
{
    "modules": true,
    "plugins": {
        "autoprefixer": {
            "browsers": [
                "Firefox >= 52",
                "Chrome >= 55",
                "ie >= 9",
                "last 4 versions",
                "Safari >= 9"
            ],
            "flexbox": "no-2009"
        },
        "postcss-modules": {
            "generateScopedName": "[path]__[name]__[local]__[hash:base64:5]",
            scopeBehaviour: 'local'
        }
    }
}
```